# In django, how is request.session.set_expiry used to log out users after idle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, session-cookies, django-sessions

I want to log users out after some period of inactivity. This question ([Logging users out of a Django site after N minutes of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539109/logging-users-out-of-a-django-site-after-n-minutes-of-inactivity)) has a reasonable looking answer.

But I'd like to understand what distinguishes request.session.set_expiry from SESSION_COOKIE_AGE. The former seems to log the user out after a fixed period regardless of activity. Isn't this also what SESSION_COOKIE_AGE does if SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST is False?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, `request.session.set_expiry` simply overrides the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` setting for that specific session. With `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False` (the default), there would be no functional difference.

In both cases, session activity is based off of when the session was last modified (unless `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` is `True`, in which case it is saved on every request, so it's effectively modified on every request)

One example is that you may want users in a certain section of your application to have a longer session expiration, so you could use `request.session.set_expiry` with a custom value in the views related to that application, and then reset it with `request.session.set_expiry(SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)` when they leave that particular section.

Answer (score 0):

[**set_expiry()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry) overrides [**SESSION_COOKIE_AGE**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age). In other words, if [**set_expiry()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry) is executed, [**set_expiry()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry) is prioritized rather than [**SESSION_COOKIE_AGE**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age).

If [**SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) is **"True"**, users are logged out if **inactive**.

If [**SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) is **"False"**, users are logged out whether **active** or **inactive**.