# How does one enforce automatic logout due to inactivity in a Django application?

Tags: django, django-sessions

In my Django application, I would like for the user to be automatically logged out after 30 minutes of inactivity, so I used this setting in settings.py:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1800
```

However, using this setting logs the user out in 30 minutes regardless of activity. How does one enforce automatic logout due to inactivity in a Django application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging users out of a Django site after N minutes of inactivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539109/logging-users-out-of-a-django-site-after-n-minutes-of-inactivity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could update the session of an user when he accesses your site. For example in a middleware, this force session to be set again.

```
class ActivateUser(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            request.session.modified = True
```

Comment: This makes update to DB on every request. Could affect performence.

Comment: @TomaszWysocki considering use cache backend or [redis backend](https://github.com/liokm/django-redisession) then

Comment: Thanks! Right, it makes a db request every time, but it works. Premature optimization aside, it's reliable :)

Answer (score 5):

As an update on this topic. Django now has the [SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST) setting which makes it a lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

[django-session-security](http://django-session-security.rtfd.org) notes the user activity based on server side and javascript events such as mousemove, keypress, etc, etc ... Also, it warns the user before expiring the session, and tries **not** to expire the session (where there any activity maybe from another browser tab ?).

Just install it and set `settings.SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER=1800`. You could also set `settings.SESSION_SECURITY_WARN_AFTER=1740`.