# Django Admin: Auto Logout And hosting questions

Tags: python, django

**Question 1**
Lets take a case where I just create a new Django file and create a new app.
In this scenario, in the admin part, How do I ensure that the user gets logged out due to inactivity and also when the user closes all the tabs related to the website.

[Im stating this scenario because all the documentations I've read so far seem a little too complex and dont explain to the point. I feel like this would help explain everything easily to a layman like me]

**Question 2**,

How do I host a website on my personal Lan Network on my IP address in such a way that the other users in my Network would have to enter a link like `xyz.com` or something?
[My job requires me to make sure that the users dont have to remember my IP addresses because there are a lot of websites being hosted on the Lan at my work place]

Answer (score 1):

For question one, maybe take a look at the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539109/logging-users-out-of-a-django-site-after-n-minutes-of-inactivity)

As for question two, if you only have to host in your private lan, you could set up your own DHCP and DNS server as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network)

It would be a good idea , in the future to ask one question at a time. This way the correct people will be able to find and answer your question.